# api gateway rest api geolocation headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am using AWS SAM CLI

According to https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/cloudfront-geolocation-headers/ geolocation is already supported and CloudFront returns with the geolocation headers; example:

```
CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Name: United States
CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region: MI
CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region-Name: Michigan
CloudFront-Viewer-City: Ann Arbor
CloudFront-Viewer-Postal-Code: 48105
CloudFront-Viewer-Time-Zone: America/Detroit
CloudFront-Viewer-Latitude: 42.30680
CloudFront-Viewer-Longitude: -83.70590
CloudFront-Viewer-Metro-Code: 505
```

I want to be able to access these using my API gateway rest API here's a sample of my aws sam template.

```
Resources:
  login:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/functions/login.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Layers:
        - !Ref dependencies
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Method: post
            Path: /login
            RestApiId:
              Ref: mainBackendApi
mainBackendApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref Stage
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Type: EDGE
      Domain:
        DomainName: !Sub
            - <hidden>
            - apiSubDomain: !FindInMap
              - stageVars
              - !Ref Stage
              - apiSubDomain
        CertificateArn: !Ref customDomainCert
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: <hidden>
```

So far, I have been researching for 5 hours now and haven't found any actual solution so I have no choice but to ask here. Hopefully someone can help me out.

I asked this question here https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2498 as well but I was turned down.

Comment: Add the cloudfront portion of your template to your question please